# PHP in string find element with id and add style

Tags: php, html, css

I have a string with HTML. How can I find div with tag #test and add to it style attribute , for example `style="page-break-inside:avoid;"` ?

Comment: It's unclear what the question is.  You can't find (well you shouldn't need to) it in PHP as PHP generates the source.  Unless your pulling it from an external source then your better off using Dom or PHPQuery.

Comment: what DIV you are talking about add code...

Answer (score 3):

Simple you can usage [PHP Html parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser).
For example hear:

```
$dom = new Dom;
$dom->load('<div id="test"><p>Hey bro, <a href="google.com">click here</a><br /> :)</p></div>');
$div = $dom->find("#test");
$div->setAttribute('style', 'page-break-inside:avoid;');
echo $dom->outerHtml;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question concerns display which is a frontend issue. PHP is backend language. You should do it with frontend language, e.g. JavaScript and jQuery:

```
$("div#test").css("page-break-inside", "avoid");
```

jQuery tutorials: [selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) and [css](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)